# mongoose CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value at path "_id"

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Here is my schema:

```
let mongoose = require('mongoose');
let schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  type: String,
  value: String,
  attributes:[mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed],
  created_at: Date,
  updated_at: Date
})
```

then I create a new collection with {type:'user_id', value: 1},
and then I get the new data with query:

```
{type: 'user_id', value: '1'}
```

it is fine, and here is the result:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5874c5dbed927207df177d3b"),
"type" : "phone",
"value" : "13811785500",
"updated_at" : ISODate("2017-01-10T11:30:19.266Z"),
"created_at" : ISODate("2017-01-10T11:30:19.266Z"),
"attributes" : [],
```

and then,I query the save collection with collection`s ObjectId:

```
models.findBydId("5874c5dbed927207df177d3b")
```

it throw error:

```
CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "5875976f8a03b2229c544c50"    at path "_id" for model "vertex"
```

can anybody tell me what`s wrong?
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you should try this->

```
models.find({"_id": ObjectId("5874c5dbed927207df177d3b")});
```

Comment: I tried, but it did`t work.still throw the save error.

Comment: well,I remove the node_modules folder and npm install again,then thing goes well.

Comment: there should be problem of the mongoose`s, the version is 4.7.4